# Error in match(x, table, non match =0L when using ggsurplot

Tags: r, survival-analysis

My code is

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(OS, DEATH) ~ high, data=datf1)
```

no error:

```
print(fit)
      n    events  median  0.95LCL 0.95UCL
C=1  106    30      62.6     62.2    65.1
C=2  190    51      63.3     62.1    64.3
```

My code that generates the error

```
ggsurvplot(fit, pval=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE,
risk.table=TRUE, surv.median.line='hv', ylab='OS', break.x.by=5, palette=cols, 
title="P_01")
```

```
Error in match (x, table, nomatch=0L):
'match' requires vector arguments
```

My libraries: dplyr, survival, survminer, ggplot2, gridExtra.
I have run this code on my data table with no issues.  But today when I run the code I am having the above error issue.  I do not believe it's due to my data input.

```
ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table=TRUE)
```

Interestingly when I run the above code, I get the correct KM plot with table, but I also get a warning message

```
Vectorized input to 'element_text()' is not officially supported. 
Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
```

Any assistance in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show a small reproducible exxample with `dput`

Comment: Can you print out the `fit`?

Comment: Yes I can print(fit) and the output is values for N, events, median, 0.95LCL/UCL.  I would now like to get the KM graph, but for some reason using the code above I can't get a plot generated

Comment: One error I saw is `conf.int=TRUE.` which should be `conf.int=TRUE,`

Comment: Can you print out the `fit` in your question and the variable `cols`?

Comment: Yes to both David Z.  For fit I am not getting any errors and the values for N, events, median, 0.95LCL/UCL are correct and match the previous time that this entire code worked.  My variable cols are all identical to the previous time.  And yes you are correct the TRUE. should be TRUE,  I correct that and still same error message

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David Z with adding in palette= c("blue", "red").  Unfortunately that addition did not fix my error issue of:                                     Vectorized input to 'element_text()' is not officially supported. 
Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's due to the variable `cols`. Can you try if this works:

```
ggsurvplot(fit, pval=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE,
           risk.table=TRUE, surv.median.line='hv', ylab='OS', break.x.by=5, palette = c("blue", "red"), 
           title="P_01")
```